# Is it safe to have a thread still running a member function of a context manager after __exit__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

In the following minimal example, `bar` continues to run after the scope of the `with` statement:

```py
import threading
import time


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, delay):
        self._delay = delay
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        time.sleep(self._delay)
        print("done")


with Foo(2) as my_foo:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=my_foo.bar)
    thread.start()

time.sleep(3)
```

It seems to work, but is it guaranteed to be safe to do so, or can it lead to undefined behavior or errors (something with dangling references or similar)?

Comment: I don't understand. The `__exit__` doesn't even do anything, so why would this cause problems?

Comment: Yes, it is thread-safe as long as no variables used in both `my_foo.bar` and `Foo.__exit__` are mutated without synchronisation.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, I meant if the object might be destroyed already (because it's running out of scope). Nothing to do with the `__exit__` itself.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Thanks, so the thread still holding a reference to the member function guarantees that the object is not destroyed, I guess. :)

Comment: `my_foo` doesn't go out of scope when the block of code after the `with` statement finishes executing. Scope in Python is not like in C-like languages. Local variables still exist after the block of code they were declared in finishes executing. See [8.5. The with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and [Python Scope & the LEGB Rule: Resolving Names in Your Code](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/).

Comment: Why do you need a context manager in this situation? If this is a reduced example, whatever is in your real `__exit__` method is probably relevant. It is also not (supposed to be) possible to cause undefined behaviour or dangling reference errors in Python - if you do, that's a bug in Python itself.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Ah, thanks a lot. I'm reading your linked pages now. :)

Comment: @Holloway Yeah, it's a reduced example. I think I reduced it at the wrong end. [This example](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/651ac23a22ab26dc25f1a8a68a551c10) might make more sense. But when you say, it should not be possible to have UB or dangling references, I guess this one is safe too, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context manager has nothing with object creation/deletion, it just guarantee us `__exit__` will be called.

In such cases it can be helpfull to see the bytecode:

```
import dis

class Foo:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

def f():
    with Foo():
        pass

dis.dis(f)
```

```
 13           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 SETUP_WITH              16 (to 22) 
              6 POP_TOP

 14           8 POP_BLOCK
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 DUP_TOP
             14 DUP_TOP
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            3 # calling __exit__
             18 POP_TOP
             20 JUMP_FORWARD            16 (to 38) # if there is no exception just go to the end
        >>   22 WITH_EXCEPT_START
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        28
             26 RERAISE
        >>   28 POP_TOP
             30 POP_TOP
             32 POP_TOP
             34 POP_EXCEPT
             36 POP_TOP
        >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

There is [SETUP_WITH](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-SETUP_WITH) which generally push `__exit__` on the stack and do some preparation in case of exception. 16 calls the `__exit__`.

To sum up, you are right, until thread is running reference counter for Foo won't be zeroed, that's why python won't collect it.